# XML Parse .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I am new to XML I am receiving the following file/string. How can I break it in C# so I can put each of the fields in my SQL server Database? BTW I don't know how to format XML in StackOverflow if somebody can tell me how to do it. I'll do it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<SystemGenerator-Document>
    <TN>42</TN>
    <OC>CR</OC>
    <HN>738</HN>
    <USERID>xxx</USERID>
    <WS>FACTORY</WS>
    <OBJID>254209</OBJID>
    <SystemGenerator-Process>
        <RNO>247989</RNO>
        <RSNO>1</RSNO>
        <OBJID>254209</OBJID>
        <ARR>03.11.2009</ARR>
        <DEP>21.11.2009</DEP>
        <NOPAX>2</NOPAX>
        <RT>1</RT>
        <SystemGenerator-Person>
                <ARR>03.11.2009</ARR>
                <DEP>21.11.2009</DEP>
                <PCIID>700842</PCIID>
                <HASPREV>FALSE</HASPREV>
                <HASSUCC>FALSE</HASSUCC>
                <NOPAX>1</NOPAX>
                <SF>N</SF>
                <GID>535372</GID>
                <SN>Torres</SN>
                <CN>Xavier</CN>
                <LN></LN>
                <VIP></VIP>
                <STREET></STREET>
                <CITY></CITY>
                <ZIP></ZIP>
                <COUNTRY></COUNTRY>
                <STATE></STATE>
                <AREA></AREA>
                <PHONE></PHONE>
                <PHONE2></PHONE2>
                <FAX></FAX>
                <FAX2></FAX2>
                <EMAIL></EMAIL>
                <EMAIL2></EMAIL2>
                <TAXID></TAXID>
                <DOB></DOB>
                <SEX>0</SEX>
                <PASSWD></PASSWD>
                <MATCHCODE></MATCHCODE>
                <ADMCODEHQ></ADMCODEHQ>
                <GT>GUEST</GT>
                <GTD>1</GTD>
                <GNR>19726</GNR>
                <GMD>738</GMD>
                <GDB>0</GDB>
                <TT>M</TT>
                <HQGID>0</HQGID>
                <CREQ>0</CREQ>
                <CREQSTATE>
                </CREQSTATE>
                <SALUTATION></SALUTATION>
                <TITLE></TITLE>
                <T-TITLE>
                </T-TITLE>
                <CARDS></CARDS>
                <RN>718</RN>
                <CAT></CAT>
                <TG>1A</TG>
                <MC>64</MC>
                <SystemGenerator-Package>
                        <FROM>03.11.2009</FROM>
                        <TO>21.11.2009</TO>
                        <SID>AL</SID>
                        <RS>CLG</RS>
                        <SIDT>P</SIDT>
                </SystemGenerator-Package>
        </SystemGenerator-Person>
        <SystemGenerator-Person>
                <ARR>03.11.2009</ARR>
                <DEP>21.11.2009</DEP>
                <PCIID>700843</PCIID>
                <HASPREV>FALSE</HASPREV>
                <HASSUCC>FALSE</HASSUCC>
                <NOPAX>1</NOPAX>
                <SF>N</SF>
                <SN>Torres</SN>
                <CN>Xavier</CN>
                <RN>718</RN>
                <CAT></CAT>
                <TG>1A</TG>
                <MC>64</MC>
                <SystemGenerator-Package>
                        <FROM>03.11.2009</FROM>
                        <TO>21.11.2009</TO>
                        <SID>AL</SID>
                        <RS>CLG</RS>
                        <SIDT>P</SIDT>
                </SystemGenerator-Package>
        </SystemGenerator-Person>
    </SystemGenerator-Process>
    <ORG>OWNER@FACTORY(3244)#4840</ORG>
</SystemGenerator-Document>
```

Comment: XML is formatted the same way as code: surround the XML content between two ` marks, or select the content and press the icon with the "1010" in the icon bar above the text editor.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688024/parse-xml-string-net

Answer (score 1):

> look at the XmlDocument class

Also, if you are using .NET Framework 3.5 or higher, you can use [the XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Comment: I think it needs to be a smidge more emphatic than that - if you can use XDocument and Linq to XML then that should almost certainly be your default choice...

Answer (score 0):

The XML was formatted wrong by the site, so I'll just assume it is some valid XML document in a single string.

If that is the case, look at the XmlDocument class, you can feed your string to it, the class will parse it, and you can then extract your values  so that you can put them in the database as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The xml has to be valid of course.

- In case you use datasets and datatables to
  persist your data you can use the
  DataSet in [this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(VS.71).aspx).
- A better way in my oppinion is to use
  objects, in that case you can use the
  [xml serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), that serializes
  your xml directly to objects. This
  does take a bit more work to get
  done, and a little more searching to
  get the serialize attributes correct, but it is worth it in my oppinion.